# Selecting specific column value WITH relations Yii Active Record

Tags: php, yii2

I am new to YII framework and using this for my Mobile application and I have used ActiveRecord in my applications . To select particular field from active query I have used like this ,

```
     $query = CollectorCustomerMaster::find() ->where(['CollectorCode'=>(int) Yii::$app->request->post('CollectorCode')])
                ->select('CustomerCode');
     $coCollector = $query->offset(0)
                ->limit(2)
                ->all();
```

CollectorCustomerMaster Model is having one relation like this(it is referring another table to get customer details)

```
      /**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getCustomer()
{
    return $this->hasOne(CustomerMaster::className(), ['CustomerCode' => 'CustomerCode']);
}
```

and to get customer details I am using this query (using with keyword),

```
   $query = CollectorCustomerMaster::find() ->where(['CollectorCode'=>(int) Yii::$app->request->post('CollectorCode')])
                ->select('CustomerCode')->with('customer');
                $coCollector = $query->offset(0)
                    ->limit(2)
                    ->all();
```

And this query returning all CustomerMaster Row values . I need only specific CustomerMasterFields,How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some error dumped in runtime log `app.log` file.
Try this:

```
$query = CollectorCustomerMaster::find() 
                ->select('TABLE_CollectorCustomerMaster.CustomerCode')
                ->with('customer')
                ->where(['TABLE_CollectorCustomerMaster.CollectorCode'=>(int) Yii::$app->request->post('CollectorCode')]);
                $coCollector = $query->offset(0)
                    ->limit(2)
                    ->all();
```

Hope it helps.